# jbuilder with Condition if .present?

Tags: conditional-statements, ruby-on-rails-7, jbuilder

```
if presenter.present?
    @presenter = presenter 
end
json.extract! @presenter.shop, :id, :name
json.schedule @presenter.formated_schedule
```

and i have this error

```
NameError:
     #   undefined local variable or method `presenter' for #<ActionView::Base:0x0000000000d6b0>
```

I tried in one line and it still doesn't work

```
@presenter = presenter if presenter.present?
json.extract! @presenter.shop, :id, :name
json.schedule @presenter.formated_schedule
```

Comment: Where is `presenter` defined? Is it in a view helper? You might have forgotten to include some module?

Comment: Are you really using [tag:jbuilder]? That is a discontinued IDE for java development.